# Given an array of numbers (integer or float) and an integer M, output M number of subsets such that the subset with the highest sum is minimised

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, linear-programming

Dear stackoverflow community,

Currently, I am attempting to solve an optimisation problem whereby given an array of numbers (integer or float; non-negative) and a positive integer M, output M number of subsets (of any suitable length) such that the subset with the highest sum among the subsets is minimised. The elements in the subsets can be non-contiguous.

> For example, given an array of [1, 4, 5, 3] and an integer M = 2, the
> desired output is [1, 5] and [4, 3], whereby the highest subset sum
> is 7 which is minimised.
>
> Another example, given an array of [3, 10, 7, 2] and an integer M = 3,
> the desired output is [3, 2], [7], and [10] or even [3, 7], [2], and
> [10] where by the minimised highest subset sum is 10.

Is there anyone who have experienced such an optimisation before? I believe this is a variant of the Kadane algorithm.

Any links, pseudo code, pythonic code, and etc. are very much appreciated.

I have thought the following procedure to solve the problem:

1. Sort the array in ascending order
2. Initialise M number of empty subsets
3. In a while loop, add the smallest and largest availableelement to each subset until no more elements are left to be selected from the parent array

Comment: I apologise, the array can only contain non-negative numbers. Thank you for pointing this out, let me edit the question.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74724846/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156016/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: It would better to say about **subsets** rather than subarrays (continuous pieces). This is rather hard optimization problem "problem of stone piles" (don't know exact English term), there is no simple exact solution.

Comment: @MBo thank you for your input, I will modify the question in accordance to your suggestion. And also, I will take a look at this "stone piles" problem, it is evident that this question of mine needs to have an actual official optimisation problem name tagged to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be viewed as a variant of an assignment problem:

Let `v[i]` be our data array and let `j=1..M` indicate the subsets. Introduce binary variables `x[i,j] ∈ {0,1}` with:

```
 x[i,j] = 1 if value i is assigned to subset j
          0 otherwise
```

Our optimization model can look like:

```
 min z
 z >= sum(i, v[i]*x[i,j])  ∀j  "largest sum"  
 sum(j, x[i,j]) = 1        ∀i   "assign each value to a subset"
 x[i,j] ∈ {0,1}
```

This is a linear mixed-integer programming problem and can be solved with any MIP solver.

A result using random data:

```
----     34 PARAMETER results  

            value        sub1        sub2        sub3        sub4        sub5        sub6        sub7        sub8        sub9       sub10

i1         17.175      17.175
i2         84.327                                                                  84.327
i3         55.038                                                      55.038
i4         30.114      30.114
i5         29.221                                                                  29.221
i6         22.405                  22.405
i7         34.983                                                                                          34.983
i8         85.627                                                                                                      85.627
i9          6.711                                                                                           6.711
i10        50.021                                                                                                                  50.021
i11        99.812                                          99.812
i12        57.873                                                                              57.873
i13        99.113                              99.113
i14        76.225                  76.225
i15        13.069                                                                              13.069
i16        63.972                                                                                                                  63.972
i17        15.952                  15.952
i18        25.008                                                                                                      25.008
i19        66.893      66.893
i20        43.536                                                                              43.536
i21        35.970                                                                                          35.970
i22        35.144                                                                                          35.144
i23        13.149                                          13.149
i24        15.010                              15.010
i25        58.911                                                      58.911
total                 114.181     114.582     114.123     112.961     113.949     113.548     114.478     112.809     110.635     113.993
```

notes:

- The solution is, in general, not unique.
- It is easy to add a constraint that forbids empty subsets. (Can happen with more skewed data sets).

Comment: Thank you @Erwin for your reply to this question, it is a relief to find out that there is a potential solution to the problem at hand. However, I have close to no experience in tackling MIP problems, and as such, could I kindly ask if you could suggest existing python libraries that you would utilise to tackle the problem. 

Also, can I trouble you update your reply with a pseudo code so that other users like myself could understand it better?

I have come across google's OR tools, but unsure if it is suitable or friendly for my usage.

Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: The mathematical model is essentially the pseudo-code. Yes, OR-Tools can be used. It supports MIP models and CP (Constraint Programming) models (the latter can be better if the values are integers). Note that the data set I used (25 values, 10 sets) makes it a somewhat difficult model to solve. State-of-art MIP solvers solve it very quickly, but other solvers may have trouble finding proven optimal solutions (but they will find good solutions very quickly). OR-tools CP solver also does a good job (but requires integer data). Of course, smaller data sets can be solved by any solver.